# How to capture on click in mesh three.js in autodesk viewer?

Tags: three.js, onclick, mesh, autodesk-viewer

I have this spheres marked in a Revit model, and i basically want to capture the click on them and show it's details.
I followed this question: [How to add event for a mesh in threejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641314/how-to-add-event-for-a-mesh-in-threejs), but, when I click in something, I'm receivig this error: "THREE.Raycaster: Unsupported camera type."

[image: Spheres in model]

My code:

```
 issues.results.map((issue) => {

    //ADDING SPHERES INTO MODEL

    const x = issue.linkedDocuments[0].details.position.x;
    const y = issue.linkedDocuments[0].details.position.y;
    const z = issue.linkedDocuments[0].details.position.z;

    let geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 32, 16);
    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff8000,
    });

    let circle = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
    circle.position.set(x, y, z);
    viewer_exports.overlays.addMesh(circle, "custom-scene");
    
    // TRYING TO CAPTURE ON CLICK

    let camera = viewer_exports.getCamera();
    let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    let mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    function onMouseMove(event) {
      mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    }

    function onMouseClick(event) {
      raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
      let isIntersected = raycaster.intersectObject(circle);
      if (isIntersected) {
        console.log("Mesh clicked!");
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick, false);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);
  });
```

I also tried to pass "camera.perspectiveCamera" to "raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);", the error doesn't appear but is logging "Mesh clicked!" anywhere I click in the screen, even out of the model.

This is my camera type in log:
[image: This is my camera log]

I read this quest too: [Click listener on custom geometry in the overlay scene - Autodesk forge viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027751/click-listener-on-custom-geometry-in-the-overlay-scene-autodesk-forge-viewer/58040197#58040197) and all of the links in the answer, the most important: [Handling custom meshes selection along model components in the Forge Viewer](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/handling-custom-meshes-selection-along-model-components-forge-viewer), but I don't realize how to use it.

I also saw the Raycaster source code:

[image: Raycaster Source Code]

That means the Unified Camera is not supported, so do I have to change the viewer camera type?

I saw too that the Viewer has a function that changes the camera, but only Unified Camera's supported:

[image: Forge docs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this way to markup models generate other scene that is overlapping the real viewer scene, then it's not able to get click events using Raycaster. The right way to markup is with Data Visualization Sprites, that give us a pretty clean documentation about them [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/sprites/create_sprite_style/)

Answer (score 0):

You can react to click event to obtain the point and geometry clicked using [clientToWorld](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#clienttoworld-clientx-clienty-ignoretransparent-ignore2dmodelbounds-ignore2dmodelson3d) method.

```js
NOP_VIEWER.container.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
  const result = NOP_VIEWER.clientToWorld(ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
  if (result) {
    console.log(result.point);
  }
});
```